# Insert a record at the particular row in a psql table

Tags: sql

I want my record to be inserted as 5th row of my table. How can i do this? Is it possible? If so, what query helps me to insert at the particular row of my table

Comment: There is no such thing as the "5th row" of a table. Rows in a table are **NOT** sorted in any way.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you